# Left join repeats same value of a column in result

Tags: mysql

I have this sql query :

```
SELECT t1.id_action, DATE_FORMAT(t1.date_creation,'%d/%m/%Y &agrave; %H:%i') AS creation_action, 
u.id_utilisateur, p.genre AS genre_utilisateur,
p.nom, av.titre_avancement, b.nom_banque, c.nom_courtier
FROM action AS t1 
LEFT JOIN type 
ON type.id_type=t1.id_type
LEFT JOIN avancement AS av
ON av.id_avancement=t1.id_avancement  
LEFT JOIN utilisateur AS u
ON u.id_utilisateur=t1.id_utilisateur 
LEFT JOIN personne AS p 
ON p.id_personne=u.id_personne
left join offre_concurrente o 
on o.id_dossier = t1.id_dossier
left join banque b 
on b.id_banque = o.id_banque
left join courtier_concurrent c 
on c.id_courtier_concurrent=o.id_courtier_concurrent
WHERE t1.id_dossier=11 AND t1.fait='1' 
GROUP BY t1.id_action
ORDER BY t1.date_creation DESC
```

And in **"b.nom_banque"** and **"c.nom_courtier"** it displays null all the other columns are okay except these 2 i can't figure out the exact problem

Comment: Your query is invalid, because you are grouping by `id_action` and then selecting a bunch of other non aggregate columns.  You should show us some sample data, along with the expected output.  It might help if you could make your question more minimal by paring down the query to say just 1 or 2 joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add all the non-aggregated columns in the select to the group by clause, but I can see you are not using any aggregate function so use DISTINCT instead. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id_action, DATE_FORMAT(t1.date_creation,'%d/%m/%Y &agrave; %H:%i') AS creation_action, 
u.id_utilisateur, p.genre AS genre_utilisateur,
p.nom, av.titre_avancement, b.nom_banque, c.nom_courtier
FROM action AS t1 
LEFT JOIN type 
ON type.id_type=t1.id_type
LEFT JOIN avancement AS av
ON av.id_avancement=t1.id_avancement  
LEFT JOIN utilisateur AS u
ON u.id_utilisateur=t1.id_utilisateur 
LEFT JOIN personne AS p 
ON p.id_personne=u.id_personne
left join offre_concurrente o 
on o.id_dossier = t1.id_dossier
left join banque b 
on b.id_banque = o.id_banque
left join courtier_concurrent c 
on c.id_courtier_concurrent=o.id_courtier_concurrent
WHERE t1.id_dossier=11 AND t1.fait='1' 
ORDER BY t1.date_creation DESC
```